# An error when passing the event object as argument

Tags: javascript, events

I have the following object code (in short):

```
var codeEditor = function() {
  ...
  // The non-highlighted code.
  this.unhighlightedCode = null;
  ...
  // "this" object
  var that = this;

  this.keys = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      default:;
    }
  };

  // Initialization
  this.init = function() {
    ...
    that.unhighlightedCode = document.getElementById("unhighlightedCode");
    that.unhighlightedCode.onkeydown = that.keys(event);
  }();
}

// The implementaion
var editor = new codeEditor;
```

The problem:
In this line `that.unhighlightedCode.onkeydown = that.keys(event);` when passing the event object.

The result:
In Firefox an error message appears: `TypeError: e is undefined`, as for the Chrome `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to pass the event, it passes itself, you should reference the function rather than call it

```
that.unhighlightedCode.onkeydown = that.keys;
```